# showing 2nd page in a paginated table in a primary content div in php

Tags: php, pagination

Good Evening/morning,
 I have a table which is paginated.  The first page shows up in a primarycontent div, which is where i want it..however when clicking on page 2, 3..etch it opens up in a different link, I want it to open up in the primary content div like the first page, but can't figure out how to do it.  Also when clicking the previous button it goes to page 1, instead of the page before the current page..ex on page 50, goes to page 1. Here is my code.

```
<?php
require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');

$display = 30;

if (isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric ($_GET['p']))
{
    $pages = $_GET['p'];

} else {

    $q = "SELECT COUNT(NewCustomerID) FROM customer";
    $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    $row = @mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_NUM);
    $records = $row[0];

    if ($records > $display){//more than 1 page.
    $pages = ceil($records/$display);
    } else {
        $pages = 1;
    }
} // end of p IF



if (isset($_GET['s']) && is_numeric ($_GET['s']))
{
        $start = $_GET['s'];
    } else {
        $start = 0;
    }

    $q = "SELECT(NewCustomerID) AS customerid,
      (OldCustomerID) AS oldcustomerid,
                    (FirstName) AS FirstName,
                    (MiddleName) AS MiddleName,
                    (LastName) AS LastName,
                    (UserName) AS UserName,
                    (CarID) AS CarID,
                    (CarColorID) AS CarColorID,
                    (ComputerID) AS ComputerID,
                    (IsLaptop) AS LaptopID,
                    (RaceID) AS RaceID,
                    (ResidenceID) AS ResidenceID,
                    (BirthMonthID) AS BirthMonthID  
    FROM  customer ORDER BY LastName ASC LIMIT $start, $display";
    $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q); if(!$r){die(mysqli_error($dbc));}

    Echo '<table>
    <tr>
        <td><b>NewCustomerID </b></td>
        <td><b>OldCustomerID </b></td>
        <td><b>FirstName </b></td>
        <td><b>MiddleName </b></td>
        <td><b>LastName </b></td>
        <td><b>UserName </b></td>
        <td><b>CarID </b></td>
        <td><b>CarColorID </b></td>
        <td><b>ComputerID </b></td>
        <td><b>IsLaptop </b></td>
        <td><b>RaceID </b></td>
        <td><b>ResidenceID </b></td>
        <td><b>BirthMonthID </b></td>
    </tr>';

    $bg = '#eeeeee'; // set initial back ground color

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $bg = ($bg =='#eeeeee' ? '#ffffff' : '#eeeeee'); // switch the background color.

    echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bg . '">
        <td>' . $row['customerid'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $row['oldcustomerid']. '</td>
        <td>' . $row['FirstName']. '</td>
        <td>' . $row['MiddleName']. '</td>
        <td>' . $row['LastName']. '</td>        
        <td>' . $row['UserName'].'</td>
        <td>' . $row['CarID'].'</td>
        <td>' . $row['CarColorID'].'</td>
        <td>' . $row['BirthMonthID'].'</td>
        <td>' . $row['ComputerID'].'</td>
        <td>' . $row['LaptopID'].'</td>
        <td>' . $row['RaceID'].'</td>
        <td>' . $row['ResidenceID'].'</td>
        </tr>'; 

    } // end of while loop

echo '</table>';
mysqli_free_result($r);
mysqli_close($dbc);

// make the links to the other pages if necessary

if ($pages >1) {
    // add some spaces and start a paragraph
    echo '<br /> <p>';
    // determine what page the script is on:
    $current_page = ($start/$display)+1;
    // if it's not the first page, make a previous link;
    if ($current_page !=1) {
        echo '<a href="#"' . ($start - $display) . ' &p=' . $pages . '">Previous   </a> '; 
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
        if ($i != $current_page) {
            echo '<a href="#" ' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . '&p=' . $pages . '">'
            . $i . '</a> ';
        }else{
            echo $i . ' ';
        }
    }// end of FOR loop

    // if it is not the last page, make a next button
    if ($current_page != $pages) {
        echo '<a href="#"' . ($start + $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '">Next</a>';
    }

    echo '</p>'; // close the paragraph
} // endo of links section
?>
```

Comment: stylistic tipes: Don't suppress errors with `@`. Bad idea. Don't use multi-line echoes - use HEREDOCs or break out of PHP mode. As for your actual question, you'd need to use client-side Javascript and AJAX calls to handle loading each page without clicking to a 'new' page.

Comment: Your links should be something like ?p=2 and not #&p=2. Your gets will never work. This probably explains why you always go back to the first page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should pass in `GET/POST` parameter which will carry the page to show. After you grab it from there, fro example in variable `$page`, you can use it SQL query with keyword `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`, like `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 2`, that gives you exactly rows from 11 to 20 items numbers.

Hope that's exactly what you need.

**EDITED**

```
<?php
    $route      = '/index.php?p='; // where to go on click page
    $total      = ($records % $display) != 0 ? floor($records / $display) + 1 : $records / $display; // total pages count
    $current    = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : 1; // current page number
    $last       = 1; // init value of the last page
?>
<p class="pager">
    <?php if ($total <= 9): ?>
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $total; $i++): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $route, $i; ?>" <?php if ($current == $i) echo 'class="acitve"'; ?>><?php echo $i; ?></a>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php
            $rbound = $current + 1;
            $lbound = $current - 1;

            if ($lbound < 1)
                $lbound = 1;

            if ($rbound > $total)
                $rbound = $total;

            for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++):
        ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $route, $i; ?>" <?php if ($current == $i) echo 'class="acitve"'; ?>><?php echo $i; ?></a>
            <?php $last = $i; ?>
        <?php endfor; ?>

        <?php if ($lbound <= $last): ?>
            <?php for ($i; $i <= $rbound; $i++): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $route, $i; ?>" <?php if ($current == $i) echo 'class="acitve"'; ?>><?php echo $i; ?></a>
            <?php $last = $i; ?>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $lbound == $last + 1 ? '' : '...'; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($lbound > 3 && $rbound < $total - 2): ?>
            <?php for ($i = $lbound; $i <= $rbound; $i++): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $route, $i; ?>" <?php if ($current == $i) echo 'class="acitve"'; ?>><?php echo $i; ?></a>
            <?php $last = $i; ?>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($rbound >= $total - 2): ?>
            <?php for ($i = $lbound; $i < $total - 2; $i++): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $route, $i; ?>" <?php if ($current == $i) echo 'class="acitve"'; ?>><?php echo $i; ?></a>
            <?php $last = $i; ?>
            <?php endfor; ?>
            <?php $last = $last > $total - 4 ? $last : $total - 2; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $rbound == $total - 3 ? '' : '...'; ?>
            <?php $last = $total - 2; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php for ($i = $total - 2; $i <= $total; $i++): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $route, $i; ?>" <?php if ($current == $i) echo 'class="acitve"'; ?>><?php echo $i; ?></a>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</p>
```

That's all in above gives you pager rendered as: `1 2 3 ... 12 13 14 ... 18 19 20`, here current page is 13, so it shows first 3 pages number, current page +/- 1 page and last 3 page numbers. So for the first page it would be: `1 2 3 ... 18 19 20`, same for the last. Also adds CSS class `active` to the current page link.

Comment: okay, sorry i have no idea.. i'm a student, i was following the book. The links did work, when i could pull them up in a new page.  The teacher wants it to NOT open in a new page, but refresh in the primary content div that we built in a previous project. The initial pull does that but not when it comes up again. Could you give me a snippet of how it should look?

Comment: Wait a sec, I'll post a full-text solution. One question - loading with AJAX, or reloading the window?

Comment: i am assumming reloading the window as i have no idea what ajax is.

Comment: so do i put this at the bottom where my current page codes are?

Comment: after `// make the links to the other pages if necessary` and before `// endo of links section` - replace everything there by code in answer.

Comment: okay did it getting   No input file specified.  but address shows:  http://itd1.cincinnatistate.edu/index.php?p=2, instead of   http://itd1.cincinnatistate.edu/PHP1_CombsW/index.php?menukey=5

Comment: edit this `$route      = '/index.php?p='; // where to go on click page` change to URL what you need from root dir, as I can see you need `$route = '/PHP1_CombsW/index.php?menukey=5&p='`. Or defined URL whatever logic based, and put it into variable `$route`.

Comment: stupid question, its loading up okay, but getting errors on Notice: Undefined variable: records in D:\WebShare\Students\Term\2LateFall\PHP\CombsW\p3Table.php on line 97

Notice: Undefined variable: records in D:\WebShare\Students\Term\2LateFall\PHP\CombsW\p3Table.php on line 97. but in the code i noticed.--'class="acitve"' in several spots, is that supposed to be active?

Comment: your var `$records` defining only if no `$_GET['p']` passed, move it above `if () {} else {}` statement...

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself a ton of time and use a pre-engineered grid.  My grid of choice is [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net)  It's got all the bugs and browser inconsistencies taken care of already, and paging is as simple as one line of code.  If you want to get really simple, you could output your entire table and let datatables sort out the paging, as well as sorting, filtering, etc.  If you're like me and have to deal with a lot of results, you can also load data via ajax and have datatables actually assemble the dom.  Either way, it's quicker than writing your own.

Comment: actually this is my final project for this class.

Comment: I have also tried - echo '<a href="index.php?menukey=5?s=' . ($start - $display) . ' &p=' . $pages . '">Previous</a> ';